# How to do this query

Tags: mysql

THere is a data table from a flower shop which looks like

```
 CustomerID        Flower

    John                peony
    John                lily
    John                Lotus

    Mary               peony
    Mary               lily
    Mary               chrysanthemum

    Lisa                chrysanthemum
    Lisa                peony
    Lisa                kapok

enter code here
```

I would like to find those customers' ID who buy the same n flowers. For example, in the above table, for peony and lily , the customers who buy both of them (n=2, for this case) are John and Mary.

I cannot figure out a SQL statement to do the above query. Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Select Customer ID, Flower from [yourtable] where Flower = 'peony' or 'lily'

Do you want it to be dynamic?

then maybe make a stored procedure with variables. More info about sp's [here](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/stored_procedures_basics_p1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

How about a self-join?

```
SELECT 
    y.CustomerID 
FROM 
    YourTable y 
JOIN 
    YourTable y2 
ON 
    y.CustomerID = y2.CustomerId 
WHERE
    y.Flower = "Lily"
AND
    y2.Flower = "Lotus"
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the table with itself.

```
SELECT a.CustomerID, b.CustomerID, a.Flower FROM flowertable a, flowertable b WHERE a.Flower = b.Flower
```

Comment: This will return `John | Mary | Lily`, he wants to return something like `John | lily and peony`

Answer (score 0):

you need something like this

```
select distinct(CustomerID) from mytable 
where flower in
(select distinct(flower) from mytable group  by  flower having count(flower) = 2)
```

you can replace **2** to any number you want !

Answer (score 0):

I would try an exists clause that would only report flowers that have more than one distinct purchaser:

```
select a.customerid, a.flower
from yourtable a
where exists
  (select 'x'
   from yourtable b 
   where b.customerid <> a.customerid
   and b.flower = a.flower)
```